# Style.xml file based on screen size

Tags: java, android

Android supports layouts for [different screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) by suffixing layout folders with a certain screen size (large, sw600 etc). Is this possible to do for styles as well? There is nothing in their documentation that I have found yet, but it seems logical to desire style.xml's that support specific screen sizes.

Comment: `styles.xml` is in `res/values` and values can be suffixed with `sw600dp` etc etc. So I think you can suffix them with screen sizes too. Though I am not completely sure, hence the comment and not the answer

Comment: @hiphopdroid Yes, that is my hope, but I haven't found anything to support it yet. I am attempting to try right now.

Comment: Ok. If there's any luck please post it as an answer (will be helpful to me as well as others)

Comment: look here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

yes
its very simple just create values folder with the right suffix , you need
EXAMPLE:

```
values-sw600  values-hdpi
```

look here at bottom of the page
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: He is talking about screen sizes `hdpi` is a screen density suffix

Comment: This is correct, but for completion could you post some example code here? It can be taken from the link.

Comment: find it for you look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html search for res/values-small/ in the page

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

Create a folder like for example values-sw600dp in the res directory and there you add your style.xml